# How to tailor rest service with docker tomcat in AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, dockerfile

Hi I am new to docker and am trying to understand how to deploy rest service in tomcat using docker container in AWS.

Basically, any rest service requires a server so I am able to deploy my war file in the tomcat app folder which is installed in an EC2 instance.

But when I go for EB applications with docker it wants me to provide a docker zip file( obviously containing the dockerfile in it). So my dockerfile should specify that i am using openjdk, then should install tomcat and setup environment variables. This part i understood.

Next transfer the war file to this tomcat location in docker.

I am stuck here how should i do this. Should i copy the war file in the docker image export ? Or is there a way to avoid this? I am looking for a way that i can build the source file using maven and deploy it to Elastic beanstalk with docker and tomcat.

Please excuse me for this confusing question and dumbness but I have read a lot of articles and  I am completely confused so asking for help here.

Comment: Wait, do you mean Elastic Beanstalk (EB), or Elastic Block Store (EBS)?

Comment: sorry elastic beanstalk

Comment: I tried adding the war file to the tomcat webapps location using ADD docker command. Deployment worked but i am looking for a way to deploy without copying from docker file as it would increase the size of the docker image export file i would be uploading. And i dont think it would be a best practice.

Comment: What exactly are you looking to customize in the Tomcat? There are in general two ways that you can do this in Elastic Beanstalk, using a customized docker image with the Docker Solution Stack like you mention, or by using ebextensions to update the existing Tomcat Solution Stack.